# Convert array to set in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, set

Is there an easier way to turn an array in to a set using c++ rather than looping through its elements?

Preferably using the standard template library

Comment: Should have mentioned I'm pretty new to C++ and come from Objective C background

Answer (score 31, accepted):

As for all standard library container types, use the [constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/set):

```
std::set<T> set(begin(array), end(array));
```

Comment: +1.  FWIW, this is still likely a loop under the hood, but the advantage is that you don't need to write that loop, and if the writers of `set` are clever, they can apply all sorts of optimizations you need not learn.

Comment: Or if you want to update an existing set `s`, then do : `s.insert(begin(array), end(array));`

Answer (score 9):

```
int a[] = {1,2,3,4};
std::set<int> s{1,2,3,4};

std::set<int> s1{std::begin(a), std::end(a)};
```

See: [Here](http://ideone.com/QHvejH)

Comment: @H2CO3 Illogical why ?

Comment: because to me, an initializer list is a list of objects to initialize the container with. This range- and iterator-based approach seems more like a constructor overload issue to me, but that's just personal opinion.

Comment: @H2CO3 that is not an initializer list, that is "uniform initialization".

Comment: @H2CO3 Terminologies damn it, I'm really bad at those too, sorry my bad

Answer (score 4):

```
#include <set>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

auto main()
    -> int
{
    static int const a[] = {3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9, 2, 6, 5, 4};
    set<int> const  numbers( begin( a ), end( a ) );
    for( auto const v : numbers ) { cout << v; }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Just wondering, why did you declare main with trailing return type?

Comment: @polkadotcadaver: I use it as a *single* function declaration syntax that works with templates, lambdas and ordinary functions. In addition to being a uniform notation it has a visual advantage, that the function name always appears at the same place visually, and the same for the return type, no matter how long or short. This is an advantage for scanning code, without having to read the details.

Comment: I see - fair enough, and your choice. I can't say personally that I will change to a less readable (imo) syntax to retain consistency, where only a tiny amount of code can't be written without it. Especially where many of those minority cases will be solved better by auto-return types soon enough.

Answer (score 0):

```
int arr{} = {1,55,4,2,35,1,5}; //declare the array
int arrSize = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]); //get size of the array
set<int> s(arr, arr+arrSize);  //move the array to the set ***
```

Comment: sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to perform some operation on the values from the array before inserting them (or as you are inserting them) into the set, you could use std::transform.